# Optimize Laravel query to get top 10 products

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-optimization

This is my Laravel code to get top 10 products .

```
$top_10_products = Product::select('id', 'name')->whereHas('cartItems', function ($query) use ($from, $to) {
            $query->whereBetween('created_at', [$from . ' 00:00:00', $to . ' 23:59:59']);
            // $query->whereHas('cart', function($query) use($from, $to){
            //     $query->whereBetween('date', [$from . ' 00:00:00', $to . ' 23:59:59']);
            // });
        })
            ->orWhereHas('invoiceItems', function ($query) use ($from, $to) {
                $query->whereBetween('created_at', [$from . ' 00:00:00', $to . ' 23:59:59']);
                $query->whereHas('invoice', function($query) use($from, $to){
                    $query->doesntHave('carts');
                    // ->whereBetween('date', [$from . ' 00:00:00', $to . ' 23:59:59']);
                });
            })
            ->withCount(['cartItems as cart_items_sum_product_price' => function ($q) use ($date, $from, $to) {
                $q->select(DB::raw('sum(carts_items.product_price_selling * (1 - (carts_items.product_remise / 100)) * carts_items.product_quantity)'))
                    ->whereBetween('created_at', [$from . ' 00:00:00', $to . ' 23:59:59']);
                // ->whereHas('cart', function($query) use($date){
                //     $query->whereBetween('date', [$to  . ' 00:00:00', $to . ' 23:59:59']);
                // });
            }])
            ->withCount(['invoiceItems as invoice_items_sum_product_price' => function ($q) use ($date, $from, $to) {
                $q->select(DB::raw('sum(invoice_items.product_price_selling * (1 - (invoice_items.product_remise / 100)) * invoice_items.product_quantity)'))
                    ->whereBetween('created_at', [$from . ' 00:00:00', $to . ' 23:59:59']);
                $q->whereHas('invoice', function($query) use($date){
                    $query->doesntHave('carts');
                // ->whereBetween('date', [$from . ' 00:00:00', $to . ' 23:59:59']);
                });
            }])
            ->orderByRaw('COALESCE( cart_items_sum_product_price , 0 ) + COALESCE( invoice_items_sum_product_price , 0 ) DESC')
            ->limit(10);
```

This code queries the database to fetch the top 10 products based on their total sales within a certain date range. It considers both the product sales that are associated with the carts_items and invoice_tems tables, and it filters out any products that don't meet the specified criteria.

The query is very slow I want to make it faster.

Comment: Do you use column indexes for the tables ?

Comment: @MahdiRashidi no

Comment: Most important speed optimization in mysql is to index columns. If you index them right you will get super fast results

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize your query by creating database column indexing.

create a migration

```php
public function up()
{
Schema::table('cart_items', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->index('created_at');
});

Schema::table('invoice_items', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->index('created_at');
});

Schema::table('cart_items', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->index('cart_id');
    $table->index('product_id');
});

Schema::table('invoice_items', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->index('invoice_id');
    $table->index('product_id');
});

Schema::table('invoices', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->index('customer_id');
});
}
```

Also consider Eager Loading. For instance instead of using `whereHas` use `with`:

```php
 Product::select('products.id', 'products.name')
    ->with([
        'cartItems' => function ($query) use ($from, $to) {
            $query->whereBetween('created_at', [$from . ' 00:00:00', $to . ' 23:59:59']);
        },
        'invoiceItems' => function ($query) use ($from, $to) {
            $query->whereBetween('created_at', [$from . ' 00:00:00', $to . ' 23:59:59'])
                ->whereHas('invoice', function($query) use($from, $to){
                    $query->doesntHave('carts');
                });
        }
    ])
```